# Who takes or who take

Tags: meaning, subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses

I’m kinda confused on this. Which one is correct, I have a sentence does it say:

> I need someone who **takes** my picture

or is it:

> I need someone who **take** my picture

?

Comment: (A) *I need someone **to take** my picture*. (B) *I need someone **who takes pictures.***

Comment: The natural way to say what I think you mean is: "*I need someone **to take** my picture*". But I think your real question is about how to know whether to use "take" or "takes" after the word "who". Am I right?

Comment: Or "I need someone who will take my picture"

Answer (score 1):

"someone who takes my picture" would mean a person who takes your picture regularly.  Unless you are a celebrity, you don't have people (who are not known to you) who take your picture.

You almost certainly mean "I need someone **to** take my picture."  The infinitive gives the purpose of you.  The infinitive form is always "take".

Answer (score 0):

"to **take**" is a verb that conjugates in the present tense to "**takes**" in the third person singular but to "take" in the first and second person singular and all plurals.

In your case

> "I need someone who takes my picture"

should be the correct one.

Comment: Can you explain how Jessi would know that it should be the third person singular? They conjugated it twice correctly in their question, so that's probably not the problem

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer considering what Jessi's looking for.